# 3 way check box (toggle)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a custom 'toggle' (using ButterscotchTheme) and I am trying to add a 3rd option.

This is how it currently is: (cant post pictures due to being new, but here is links to the pictures)

[image]

[image]

I would like a third option. I have checked the theme code and it is done by Checkbox rules. And I know a Tricheckbox is a thing, I am just unsure how to get it to work. I did some research and was unable to figure it out in this situation.

Here is all the Themes toggle code:

```
Public Class ButterscotchToggle : Inherits Control

Private _check As Boolean
Public Property Checked As Boolean
    Get
        Return _check
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _check = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property

Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
    DoubleBuffered = True
    BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Size = New Size(80, 25)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Checked = Not Checked
    MyBase.OnClick(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim b As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Width, Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b)
    Dim outerrect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1)
    Dim maininnerrect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(7, 7, Width - 15, Height - 15)
    Dim buttonrect As New LinearGradientBrush(outerrect, Color.FromArgb(100, 90, 80), Color.FromArgb(48, 43, 39), 90S)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    g.Clear(BackColor)
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    g.FillPath(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(40, 37, 33)), RoundRect(outerrect, 5))
    g.DrawPath(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)), RoundRect(outerrect, 5))
    g.FillPath(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(26, 25, 21)), RoundRect(maininnerrect, 3))
    g.DrawPath(New Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)), RoundRect(maininnerrect, 3))
    If Checked Then
        g.FillPath(buttonrect, RoundRect(New Rectangle(3, 3, CInt((Width / 2) - 3), Height - 7), 7))
        g.DrawString("ON", New Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(246, 180, 12)), New Rectangle(2, 2, CInt((Width / 2) - 1), Height - 5), New StringFormat() With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})
    Else
        g.FillPath(buttonrect, RoundRect(New Rectangle(CInt((Width / 2) - 3), 3, CInt((Width / 2) - 3), Height - 7), 7))
        g.DrawString("OFF", New Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(246, 180, 12)), New Rectangle(CInt((Width / 2) - 2), 2, CInt((Width / 2) - 1), Height - 5), New StringFormat() With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})
    End If
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(b, New Point(0, 0))
    g.Dispose() : b.Dispose()
End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Theme downloaded from [Butterscotch Theme GDI+](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?777631-THEME-Butterscotch-Theme-GDI-20-Controls-VB-Net)

Comment: The VB.NET programming language by itself has no "Butterscotch theme". You appear to be talking about a specific UI framework (Windows Forms, from the looks of your code) paired with an add-on controls toolkit / library... which one? Please add the relevant details to your post, as text and/or tags if possible.

Comment: There is no code there to handle a third state. CodeProject is a good place to look for this sort of thing,

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?777631-THEME-Butterscotch-Theme-GDI-20-Controls-VB-Net is where I got it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to change that boolean property to an integer (or even better, create an enum):

```
Private _check As Integer

Public Property Checked As Integer
  Get
    Return _check
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As Integer)
    _check = value
    Invalidate()
  End Set
End Property
```

Change the OnClick behavior:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As EventArgs)
  If Checked + 1 > 2 Then
    Checked = 0
  Else
    Checked += 1
  End If
  MyBase.OnClick(e)
End Sub
```

and then adjust the drawing accordingly (placing the third option in the middle I'm guessing):

```
Select Case Checked
  Case 0
    g.FillPath(buttonrect, RoundRect(New Rectangle(CInt((Width / 2) - 3), 3, CInt((Width / 2) - 3), Height - 7), 7))
    g.DrawString("OFF", New Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(246, 180, 12)), New Rectangle(CInt((Width / 2) - 2), 2, CInt((Width / 2) - 1), Height - 5), New StringFormat() With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})
  Case 1
    g.FillPath(buttonrect, RoundRect(New Rectangle(3, 3, CInt((Width / 2) - 3), Height - 7), 7))
    g.DrawString("ON", New Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(246, 180, 12)), New Rectangle(2, 2, CInt((Width / 2) - 1), Height - 5), New StringFormat() With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})
  Case 2
    g.FillPath(buttonrect, RoundRect(New Rectangle((Width / 2) - (Width / 4), 3, CInt((Width / 2) - 3), Height - 7), 7))
    g.DrawString("???", New Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(246, 180, 12)), New Rectangle((Width / 2) - (Width / 4), 2, CInt((Width / 2) - 1), Height - 5), New StringFormat() With {.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center})
End Select
```

Comment: Ok so I am using this

'If ExpandToggle.Checked + 1 > 2 Then
            ExpandToggle.Checked = 0
            MsgBox("0")
        Else
            ExpandToggle.Checked += 1
            MsgBox("1")
        End If'

How do I get the 3rd option?

Comment: @dwb You are going to have to think this through.  Remove your MsgBox code, and after the End If, just have MsgBox(Checked).